# Build Error: File not found after Time-Machine Restore to new SSD (Xcode)

Tags: xcode, compiler-errors, three20

I restored a time-machine backup onto my new SSD. Since then, I can't build my Xcode project anymore. 
It gives me an error at the #import  line, saying
'Three20/Three20.h' file not found.

How is that possible, the files are still there, in the same place. I don't even know where to start searching. Any ideas or clues?

Comment: What is your include path in your XCode environment?

Comment: i checked all infos that i could and ended up in starting a new project, copying in all old files and: it worked... the whole thing took about 6 hours, but now it's working again. don't ask me why. thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your header search files probably were cached inside Xcode cache folder and when you restore from time machine, these cache files weren't restored.

if you want, try to compare the header search folder in both projects to see the difference.

The project should have these: (assuming your project is located on the same folder as three20 is)

```
 HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../three20 
                       $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/../../three20         
                       ../three20/Build/Products/three20
```